# CountIf and SumProduct in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, unique

I am trying to count the number of unique values in a table column. I have set the range as the relevant column in the table. In defining the number of unique values to count I am getting the following error:

Required_Rows = WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(1 / WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Rng), Range(Rng)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to use Sumproduct and SumIf in that manner.  Try using the Evaluate method instead...

```
Dim Required_Rows As Variant 'declared as Variant in case Evaluate returns error

Required_Rows = Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A1:A10,A1:A10))")

If Not IsError(Required_Rows) Then
    'do something
Else
    'do something else
End If
```

Note that Evaluate has a 255 character limit.

**EDIT**

With the Range object you've defined (ie. Rng), try...

```
Required_Rows = Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(" & Rng.Address(external:=True) & "," & Rng.Address(external:=True) & "))")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! This does help, except as I have already defined the range I get an error when I do this? Required_Rows = Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(" & Rng & "," & Rng & "))")